# Jpa persisting an entity after setting id to zero

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following three entities

```
@Entity
class Session {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
     @JoinColumn(name="session_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private List<Testcase> testcases;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="session_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private List<SessionChart> sessionCharts;
}

@Entity
class SessionChart {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="sessionChart_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private List<ChartMeasurement> chartMeasurement;

}


@Entity
class ChartMeasurement {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "testcase_id", nullable=true, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Testcase testcase;
}
```

and its corresponding getters and setters. Creating a new session and persisting it with out any session charts and chart measurements works great. But I have a save as functionality when I can open a previous saved session from a different user and rename it (change the owner as me) and resave it thus creating a new database record. I do this by setting id 0 to the entity and all its sub entities, that is Testcases list sessionCharts list and all chartMeasurement entitites inside sessionCharts list. But when trying to persist I get the following error

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : ChartMeasurement.testcase -> Testcase
```

How can I overcome this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you are using JPA and thus are using an javax.persistence.EntityManager instance.

I would suggest *detaching* the object before changing the ID's and performing a persist.

For example,

```
entityManager.detach(instanceOfYourObjectHere);
```

What's happening is that the Session is holding a reference to your object instance and is confused as you have changed the primary keys.

Comment: personally, i think it'd be even better if you implemented copy-constructors and just created a copy of the original, then modified the copy.

Comment: You know, that also works and is what I actually do in my code. I was a bit torn but I decided to answer within the scope of his question. All our entity beans can be serialized as JSON. Thus we _clone_ an object by marshaling to and from JSON. We end up with a totally new instance  of which the Session does not contain a reference. Problem solved.

Comment: yes I am using jpa. Detach will detach all of my objects that under session and under sessionchart correct?and then make all Id's to zero. The alternative solution with constructor would have to create new entity objects for all referenced entity as session chart and chartMeasurement. What happens when my testcase in my chart measurement points to a testcase with id = 5 and I detatch that testcase thum making id=0? That would lead to issues correct?

Comment: Unfortunatelly leaving the ManyToOne with no cascade option set up, gives the same exception. I am copying new Instance and making all id's 0. If I activate CascadeType.ALL in ManyToOne field, then it works creating the new Session with copies but It won't let me save the session again, saying I am doing mutiple merges of detached testcase objects.

Comment: Don't perform a merge (update). Perform a _persist_. See how that works.